# Widget on click intent extras not seen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I have build a widget with an imageview. I want when the user clicks on the imageview, an activity will be started. That activity gets extras from the intent(strings, ints). It almost works, but when the widget updates, the old extras are get, not the new ones, given in the AppWidgetProvider. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Simon

AppWidgetProvider:

```
package com.aquariumzoekenpro.android;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import com.aquariumzoekenpro.android.VissenDB.Vis;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Vissen";
    static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    PendingIntent pendingintent;
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){       
//      final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);            
            int rbitem = sharedPreferences.getInt("RBitem", 0);
//          int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];          

            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);            
            VissenDB db = new VissenDB();
            int maxlength = db.lijst.size();
            Random r = new Random();
            int random = r.nextInt(maxlength - 0);      
            Vis v = db.lijst.get(random);
            int imageresource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(v.afbeelding, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(imageresource);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);         
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_imageview, bm);            

            Intent clickintent = new Intent(context, VissenBeschrijving.class);
            clickintent.putExtra("list", rbitem);
            String text = "";
            if (rbitem == 0){
                text = v.naam;
            }else{
                text = v.latijnseNaam;
            }
            clickintent.putExtra("selected", text);
            clickintent.putExtra("Herkomst", "Encyclo");
            clickintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);          
            pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, clickintent, 0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_imageview, pendingintent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);




    }
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

        int width = bm.getWidth();      
        int height = bm.getHeight();        
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;      
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;       
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION     
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();       
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP       
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);      
        // RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP      
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);     
        return resizedBitmap;

     }

}
```

VissenBeschrijving (receiving activity):

```
    i = this.getIntent();       
    VissenDB db = new VissenDB();
    String h = i.getStringExtra("Herkomst");

    if (i != null && h !=null){
        text = i.getStringExtra("selected");
        RBitem = i.getIntExtra("list", -1);
        if (RBitem == 0){
            //Nederlandse naam
            for (VissenDB.Vis v : db.lijst) {
                if (v.naam.equals(text)){
                    vis = v;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            //Latijnse naam
            for (VissenDB.Vis v : db.lijst) {
                if (v.latijnseNaam.equals(text)){
                    vis = v;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I recall correctly this is because it will reuse the old intent if nothing has change in the content.

Try adding something **unique** to your click intent.
For example:

```
clickintent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("myapp://widget/id/#togetituniqie" + appWidgetId), String.valueOf(appWidgetId)));
```

This is assuming you know the appWidgetId.
Otherwise you can use something else unique. Like **UUID.randomUUID().toString()**

Comment: Thanks this works great! This is what I added: `clickintent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("myapp://widget/id/#togetituniqie" + thisWidget), UUID.randomUUID().toString()));`

Comment: This helped.
In my case i added an unique ACTION to the intent like:
`intent.setAction("SOME_PREFIX_" + appWidgetId)`

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked just adding the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to the pending intent in the widget provider.

So, in this case it would be:

```
pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, clickintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This way it seems that the old pending intent used to open the activity gets updated with the new content sent from the widget provider, including the inner intent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved simply adding `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` flag (if you want the intent is fired once) or `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` (if you want it will be executed on every click event):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourWidgetProvider.class);
intent.setAction(ACTION_NAME);
intent.putExtra("extraName", extraValue);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.view_id, pendingIntent);
```